How can I make my bees move from nest to hive?
I found some bees not too far from my house, but I would like to just walk out an harvest from them. I tried attracting them with a flower over to the hive, but once we get there, they fly back.
The only thing I've managed to do is bring the bees to the hive and breed two of them to make a baby bee - the baby stayed at the hive, while the adult bees went back to the nest.
How do I have them stay at the hive? I'm playing on 1.21.51.

Can't you just remove the nest and bring it where you need?

@pinckerman I'll try that. Will the bees attack if they see me break their nest?

@Alex you have to put a campfire a couple of blocks below, that will pacify the bees inside and let you break the hive (if you have a pickaxe with silk touch)

@pinckerman seems like your comments could be moved into an answer

You can't move bees, but you can instead break and move the beehive using a Silk Touch pickaxe. This will also prevent them becoming angry.

Keep in mind that, if you want to harvest the honey, you need a campfire a couple of blocks below the beehive, this will let you interact with the hive without making them angry.
From the Minecraft wiki:

Placing a campfire under a beehive or bee nest allows honey bottles and honeycomb to be harvested without provoking the bees. There must be unobstructed air between the campfire and the beehive or bee nest.


Finding the Silk Touch Enchantment will be a bit of a struggle since I'm not a pro at playing Survival on BE compared to Wii U Edition, but this will do.

@Alex fishing is a safe and easy way to get enchantments, if you have patience :)

I like that idea. I just planted a lot of Cheery Trees at my home, and I love watching the flower peddles fall off the trees, so I'll make a pond there and fish under the trees.
